# JQuery plugin function not found on a Cheetah Template

Tags: jquery, validation, compatibility, cheetah

I am trying to make a comment form for a website that allows users to leave their name, email, and a comment on an html file that is a cheetah template. I want to use this JQuery plugin to validate input: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

I can get the function to work in its own file using the demo code, but when I try to apply it to the cheetah template, Firebug gives me the following error:

```
$("#feedbackform").validate is not a function
[Break On This Error] $("#feedbackform").validate();
```

I am setting the cheetah variable to '@' to accommodate use of '$' for JQuery, then calling the function, as follows:

```
#compiler-settings
cheetahVarStartToken=@
#end compiler-settings
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#feedbackform").validate();
    });
</script>
#compiler-settings reset
```

Here is the code for the form:

```
<form id="feedbackform" action="leavefeedback.html" method="GET">
    <table cellpadding="8" style="width:600px;"><tr>

        <td valign="top" align="right" >Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="fname" name="name" class="required" minlength="2" size="30"></td></tr>

        <tr><td valign="top" align="right" >Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="femail" name="email" class="required email" size="30"></td></tr>

        <tr><td valign="top" align="right" style="width:100px" >Comment</td><td>
        <textarea name="feedback" id="fcomment" class="required" rows="10" style="width:400px;"></textarea>
        <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you include the validation plugin _after_ jquery?

Comment: I ended up resolving this issue myself. The site I am working on uses an <iframe> tag, which the src hyperlink was not escaping, so I downloaded the plugin file and used a direct filepath.